# Ruby On Rails - How to send information on a button click and display information from two models on the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Ruby on Rails (and MVC) and am going around in circles trying to implement something. It relates to routing, and passing information from a button click on a static page to another class then rendering information from two different models (that have a relationship set up). Any help is much appreciated:-

So I generated users, matches and matchPicks scaffolds in rails on Nitrious.io and everything with them is fine. I think I understand most of how the routing goes re: GET, POST etc.

I then created a static page called blocks that has a number of buttons on it (Button 1 - 10). What I want to do is the following:-

- If the user clicks Button 1, relevant information on the matches (from the match model) in block 1 render as well as drop-down menus (from the match_picks model) that allow the user enter their team selection.
- If the user clicks Button 2, relevant information on the matches (from the match model) in block 2 render as well as drop-down menus (from the match_picks model) that allow the user enter their team selection.
- And so on.....

I think I have my relationships set up properly (see models code below) but my questions are:-

1. How do I pass information on what button was clicked (i.e. the block number) to the match_picks controller? And then how do I take that information in the match_picks controller and only display the relevant matches with the same block number?
2. Assuming I got the above working, I would only be displaying information from the match_picks database (in the match_pick/index view). How do I also show information from the match database in this view?

I'm pulling my hair out at this stage on how to implement it. I've read loads but am still so confused. I've posted some code below. If some other information is needed let me know.

Thanks for reading (and hopefully helping).

> **user.rb**

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :username, :password, :password_confirmation, :admin
  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password
  has_many :match_picks

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :username, :on => :create
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :username

  def self.authenticate_by_email(email, password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def self.authenticate_by_username(username, password)
    user = find_by_username(username)
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end    
end
```

> **match.rb**

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :block, :round, :date, :day, :time, :venue, :team1, :team2, :played
  has_many :match_picks
end
```

> **match_pick.rb**

```
class MatchPick < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :userID, :matchID, :userPick, :result, :points, :closed     
      belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :match
end
```

> **routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :match_picks

  resources :matches

  root :to=>"home#index"
  get "sign_in" => "authentication#sign_in"
  # get "home" => "authentication#login"  
  # get "instructions" => 'home'
  get "signed_out" => "authentication#signed_out"
  get "new_user" => "authentication#new_user"
  post "sign_in" => "authentication#login"
  put "sign_in" => "authentication#login"
  post "new_user" => "authentication#register"
  put "new_user" => "authentication#register"
  get "admin_users" => "admin#users"
  delete "user/:id" => "admin#delete_user", :as => "user"
  get "admin_users" => "authentication#admin_users"
  get '/home', to: 'home#home'
  get '/instructions', to: 'home#instructions'
  get '/blocks', to: 'home#blocks'  

end
```

> **schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140507123848) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "match_picks", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "userID"
    t.integer  "matchID"
    t.integer  "userPick"
    t.integer  "result"
    t.integer  "points"
    t.boolean  "closed"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "matches", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "block"
    t.string   "round"
    t.date     "date"
    t.string   "day"
    t.string   "time"
    t.string   "venue"
    t.string   "team1"
    t.string   "team2"
    t.integer  "result"
    t.string   "resultString"
    t.boolean  "played"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password_hash"
    t.string   "password_salt"
    t.boolean  "admin"
    t.integer  "points"
    t.integer  "leagues",       array: true
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

> **views/home/blocks.html.erb**

```
<div class= " col-md-1 text-center">

<h1>Matches</h1>

<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<% today=Date.today %>
<!--<% @today="2014-06-12".to_date %>-->

<div>
  <div>
    <%= button_to "Match Block 1", matches_path, :id => "open-contacts-dialog-btn", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary", :method => :get %>
      <% block1Close = "2014-06-11".to_date %>
      <% if today<=block1Close %>
      <p style="color:black; background: #FFFFF2; display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #000066;padding: 4px;">This block's match selections must be made before 00:00 on 12th June 2014 </p>
      <% else %>
      <p style="color:black; background: #FFFFF2; display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #000066;padding: 4px;">This block is now closed to selections. You can check your picks and see results only</p>
      <% end %> 
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= button_to "Match Block 2", matches_path, :id => "open-contacts-dialog-btn", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary", :method => :get %>
      <% block1Close = "2014-06-14".to_date %>
      <% if today<=block1Close %>
      <p style="color:black; background: #FFFFF2; display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #000066;padding: 4px;">This block's match selections must be made before 00:00 on 14th June 2014 </p>
      <% else %>
      <p style="color:black; background: #FFFFF2; display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #000066;padding: 4px;">This block is now closed to selections. You can check your picks and see results only</p>
      <% end %> 
  </div>

    <div>
    <%= button_to "Match Block 3", matches_path, :id => "open-contacts-dialog-btn", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary", :method => :get %>
      <% block1Close = "2014-06-18".to_date %>
      <% if today<=block1Close %>
      <p style="color:black; background: #FFFFF2; display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #000066;padding: 4px;">This block's match selections must be made before 00:00 on 18th June 2014 </p>
      <% else %>
      <p style="color:black; background: #FFFFF2; display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #000066;padding: 4px;">This block is now closed to selections. You can check your picks and see results only</p>
      <% end %> 
  </div>


    <div>
    <%= button_to "Match Block 4", matches_path, :id => "open-contacts-dialog-btn", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary", :method => :get %>
      <% block1Close = "2014-06-21".to_date %>
      <% if today<=block1Close %>
      <p style="color:black; background: #FFFFF2; display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #000066;padding: 4px;">This block's match selections must be made before 00:00 on 21st June 2014 </p>
      <% else %>
      <p style="color:black; background: #FFFFF2; display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #000066;padding: 4px;">This block is now closed to selections. You can check your picks and see results only</p>
      <% end %> 
  </div>


    <div>
    <%= button_to "Match Block 5", matches_path, :id => "open-contacts-dialog-btn", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary", :method => :get %>
      <% block1Close = "2014-06-24".to_date %>
      <% if today<=block1Close %>
      <p style="color:black; background: #FFFFF2; display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #000066;padding: 4px;">This block's match selections must be made before 00:00 on 24th June 2014 </p>
      <% else %>
      <p style="color:black; background: #FFFFF2; display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #000066;padding: 4px;">This block is now closed to selections. You can check your picks and see results only</p>
      <% end %> 
  </div>


    <div>
    <%= button_to "Match Block 6", matches_path, :id => "open-contacts-dialog-btn", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary", :method => :get %>
      <% block1Close = "2014-06-28".to_date %>
      <% if today<=block1Close %>
      <p style="color:black; background: #FFFFF2; display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #000066;padding: 4px;">This block's match selections must be made before 00:00 on 28th June 2014 </p>
      <% else %>
      <p style="color:black; background: #FFFFF2; display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #000066;padding: 4px;">This block is now closed to selections. You can check your picks and see results only</p>
      <% end %> 
  </div>


    <div>
    <%= button_to "Match Block 7", matches_path, :id => "open-contacts-dialog-btn", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary", :method => :get %>
      <% block1Close = "2014-06-30".to_date %>
      <% if today<=block1Close %>
      <p style="color:black; background: #FFFFF2; display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #000066;padding: 4px;">This block's match selections must be made before 00:00 on 30th June 2014 </p>
      <% else %>
      <p style="color:black; background: #FFFFF2; display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #000066;padding: 4px;">This block is now closed to selections. You can check your picks and see results only</p>
      <% end %> 
  </div>


    <div>
    <%= button_to "Match Block 8", matches_path, :id => "open-contacts-dialog-btn", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary", :method => :get %>
      <% block1Close = "2014-07-04".to_date %>
      <% if today<=block1Close %>
      <p style="color:black; background: #FFFFF2; display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #000066;padding: 4px;">This block's match selections must be made before 00:00 on 4th July 2014 </p>
      <% else %>
      <p style="color:black; background: #FFFFF2; display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #000066;padding: 4px;">This block is now closed to selections. You can check your picks and see results only</p>
      <% end %> 
  </div>


    <div>
    <%= button_to "Match Block 9", matches_path, :id => "open-contacts-dialog-btn", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary", :method => :get %>
      <% block1Close = "2014-07-08".to_date %>
      <% if today<=block1Close %>
      <p style="color:black; background: #FFFFF2; display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #000066;padding: 4px;">This block's match selections must be made before 00:00 on 8th July 2014 </p>
      <% else %>
      <p style="color:black; background: #FFFFF2; display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #000066;padding: 4px;">This block is now closed to selections. You can check your picks and see results only</p>
      <% end %> 
  </div>


    <div>
    <%= button_to "Match Block 10", matches_path, :id => "open-contacts-dialog-btn", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary", :method => :get %>
      <% block1Close = "2014-07-12".to_date %>
      <% if today<=block1Close %>
      <p style="color:black; background: #FFFFF2; display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #000066;padding: 4px;">This block's match selections must be made before 00:00 on 12th July 2014 </p>
      <% else %>
      <p style="color:black; background: #FFFFF2; display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #000066;padding: 4px;">This block is now closed to selections. You can check your picks and see results only</p>
      <% end %> 
  </div>


  <%= button_to "Match Picks", match_picks_path, :id => "open-contacts-dialog-btn", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary", :method => :get %>


</div>

</div>
```

> **views/match_picks/index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Listing match_picks</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Userid</th>
      <th>Matchid</th>
      <th>Userpick</th>
      <th>Result</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Closed</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @match_picks.each do |match_pick| %>
      <tr>
    <td><%= match_pick.userID %></td>
    <td><%= match_pick.matchID %></td>
    <td><%= match_pick.userPick %></td>
    <td><%= match_pick.result %></td>
    <td><%= match_pick.points %></td>
    <td><%= match_pick.closed %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', match_pick %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_match_pick_path(match_pick) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', match_pick, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Match pick', new_match_pick_path %>
```

> **EDIT 1**

I can't get it to pass the parameter. here's the relevant code:

> **In blocks.html.erb**

```
<%= button_to "Match Block 1", matches_path(first_match: 1), :id => "open-contacts-dialog-btn", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary", :method => :get %>
```

> **In matches_controller.rb**

```
  def index
    if(params[:first_match].equal?(1))    
      @matches = Match.all 
      puts "The Test is true"
      puts "The value of first_match is" + params[:first_match].to_s
    else
      @matches = Match.where(:id => 1..10)
      puts "This test is false"
      puts "The value of first_match is" + params[:first_match].to_s
     end
  end
```

The test keeps failing so enters the else and the debug line comes out as "The value of first_match is " (i.e. no value). I can't figure out why it's not passing the value of the parameter

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Rails!

To pass a variable to a controller you can simply add a parameter to the path like this :

```
<%= link_to 'Show', match_path(match_pick, id: my_value) %>
```

And you will get it in the controller like this

```
params[:id]
```

To display a different views with different models you can have a method in your controller like this :

```
def show
  @match = Match.find(params[:id])
  @match_picks = @match.match_picks
end
```

You can use it in your by simply calling `@match` or `@match_pick`. You can also display a different view by using [the render method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render).

If you want to show a specific view for each block, you should create more views.

Comment: Thanks Dougui I'm trying to do it now. Can you tell me do I need to define the my_param anywhere? As in, how does the receiving controller know what data type it is? If I have to define it, where and how do I do it? Do I add it to attr_accessible of the match_pick model?

Comment: What you get when you do `params[:my_params]`, it's always a string. In your model, you don't need to define it. You don't need to define the type of a variable anywhere. How rails know what is the type of an attribute is a good question. I think it comes from the database. In your file `db/schema.rb`, there is all tables with all columns and types. I will check it.

Comment: I read the rails source code but I still don't understand how rails do. What I know is if id do `User.columns[:username].` you will have the type of the column "username" in the table "users".

Comment: Thanks Dougui. I'm having a nightmare trying to get it to work. I'll have a few more goes then post some more code.

Comment: I edited my answer. What is your current difficult. Can you find the model in your controller? Can you display a variable from the controller to the view? Do you have an error? Can you display the code of your controller?

Comment: I wasn't able to fit more details in the comment section Dougui so I've edited my original post. Thanks for helping so far. I haven't a clue what I'm doing wrong

Comment: `params[:first_match].equal?(1)` will always be false because `params[:first_match]` is a string. Try this `params[:first_match].to_i == 1.

Comment: No that didn't work either. It's definitely not passing the parameter because the debug line is returning nothing for the value of first_match

Comment: You can check variables in params by simply do `puts params`. You can also use a debugger like pry.

Answer (score 0):

The button_to is the problem Dougui. When I change button_to to link_to (as per your answer) it works fine and the parameters get passed. Thanks for the `puts params`tip and all your help. I'll read the link on the render method tomorrow.